# Verify that file exists inside the Tensorflow flow. Using tf.gfile.Exists with string Tensor as input

Tags: python, tensorflow

Using Tensorflow I am trying to verify that a file exists before reading it with `tf.read_file(filename)`. Unfortunately, the way my pipeline is setup, I am generating the filename string on the fly using `tf` commands. I generate my filename string using `tf.string_join` and then would like to verify that the file exists by calling `tf.gfile.Exists`. Unfortunately, `tf.gfile.Exists` only accepts strings, and not Tensors. How can I verify that a file exists within Tensorflow? Can I evaluate the tensor at runtime? Any other workaround or a proper way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

I just wrapped it inside a `tf.py_func`

```
def file_exists(file_path):
    [exists] = tf.py_func(_file_exists, [file_path], [tf.bool])
    exists.set_shape([])

    return exists

def _file_exists(file_path):
    return tf.gfile.Exists(file_path)
```